# Why does AWS Elastic Beanstalk fail on deploy when running `assets:precomile` due to "process out of memory" when it works on SSH?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, webpack, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hope *anyone* can help me here.
I've deployed a super simple Rails 6 app with `webpacker` to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Following [this tutorial](https://austingwalters.com/rails-6-on-elastic-beanstalk/), I added a `container_command` in my `.ebextensions/` config files:

```
[...]
container_commands:
  01_precompile:
    command: bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I want to add that this has worked fine for a bunch of deploys, as long as all I had added to my app was Bootstrap 4 and Font Awesome.
Then I added `plotly.js-cartesian-dist-min` to my package.json and redeployed. Now my *t2.micro*-EC2 explodes every time on deploy and throws me an error in the above command that looks a lot like it ran out of memory:

```
Application update failed at 2020-09-17T17:22:29Z with exit status 1 and error: container_command 08_precompile in .ebextensions/packages.config failed.
yarn install v1.22.5 [1/4]
Resolving packages... success
Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.98s.
I, [2020-09-17T17:15:46.973099 #7938] INFO -- : Writing /var/app/ondeck/public/assets/manifest-b4bf6e57a53c2bdb55b8998cc94cd00883793c1c37c5e5aea3ef6749b4f6d92b.js
I, [2020-09-17T17:15:46.973347 #7938] INFO -- : Writing /var/app/ondeck/public/assets/manifest-b4bf6e57a53c2bdb55b8998cc94cd00883793c1c37c5e5aea3ef6749b4f6d92b.js.gz
I, [2020-09-17T17:15:46.973491 #7938] INFO -- : Writing /var/app/ondeck/public/assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css
I, [2020-09-17T17:15:46.973578 #7938] INFO -- : Writing /var/app/ondeck/public/assets/application-04024382391bb910584145d8113cf35ef376b55d125bb4516cebeb14ce788597.css.gz
Compiling...
Compilation failed: 
<--- Last few GCs ---> 
[7984:0x3ce65d0] 400787 ms: Scavenge 426.7 (535.4) -> 418.6 (535.4) MB, 12.0 / 0.0 ms allocation failure 
[7984:0x3ce65d0] 400832 ms: Scavenge 437.1 (542.1) -> 428.8 (542.1) MB, 3.7 / 0.0 ms allocation failure 
[7984:0x3ce65d0] 401135 ms: Scavenge 446.3 (551.1) -> 432.3 (551.1) MB, 9.5 / 4.1 ms allocation failure 
[7984:0x3ce65d0] 401267 ms: Scavenge 452.3 (555.5) -> 446.4 (556.0) MB, 22.5 / 1.9 ms allocation failure 
<--- JS stacktrace ---> 
Cannot get stack trace in GC. FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - process out of memory 
1: node::Abort() [node] 
2: 0x8cd49c [node] 
3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [node] 
4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node] 
5: 0xa6813b [node] 
6: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::Evacuate() [node] 
7: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::CollectGarbage() [node] 
8: v8::internal::Heap::MarkCompact() [node] 
9: v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node] 
10: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node] 
11: v8::internal::Factory::NewUninitializedFixedArray(int) [node] 
12: 0xd84573 [node] 
13: v8::internal::Runtime_GrowArrayElements(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node] 
14: 0x3103ac0042fd.
```

Just for fun, here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my_app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.14.0",
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "ify-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "plotly.js-cartesian-dist-min": "^1.55.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

And now, what annoys me:
When I ...

1. deploy without the precompilation step (just to get my code uploaded)
2. then SSH into my EC2 with `eb ssh`
3. navigate into the folder where the above `container_command`fails (`cd /var/app/ondeck`)
4. get `sudo su` and run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

... the precomiplation runs through with no problem.

Can you point me to what is going wrong on deploy and how I can make sure the `container_command` can leverage the amount of memory it needs?
By the way, I have already tried setting `NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=350"` in my EB environment. Played with anything from 200MB to 650MB, it still crashes.